# PHP - Twilio Recording Duration Value Issue

Tags: php, mysqli, twilio

So I'm creating an application that allows users to record a message through Twilio and I'm attempting to store the RecordingSID, the date it was created, and the duration of the recording in a MySQLi database right after the recording has been made.  I've managed to get the RecordingSID by taking the last 34 digits off the RecordingURL using the substr() function and am simply getting whatever today's date is for the date created field in my database table.  However, seemingly regardless of how long the actual recording is, I'm continually getting a value of 8 when attempting to get the recording duration.  Here's what I've got right now (with database inserts omitted since they work):

```
<?php
    $recordingURL = $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl'];
    $recordingSID = substr($recordingURL, -34);

    date_default_timezone_set('EST');
    $dateCreated = date("Y-m-d");

    $duration = $_REQUEST['RecordingDuration'];
?>
```

Any help with this matter would be fantastic!  Thanks!

Edit: I've also tried the following solution in place of the last line in my previous code snippet:

```
<?php
    $recordings = $client->account->recordings->getIterator(0, 50, array('Sid' => $recordingSID,));
    foreach ($recordings as $recording) 
    {
        $duration = $recording->duration;
    }
?>
```

Comment: is it becomes 8 when you insert database, or it gets 8 at $duration line. are you sure you are sending correct value as RecordingDuration parameter... your code seems correct to me.

Comment: Duration is 8 at the $duration line.  And I'm pretty sure I'm sending the correct value as the RecordingDuration parameter as I've also tried pulling the recording from the list of recordings associated with my Twilio account with the recordingSID as my key to get the right recording, but that also returns a recording duration of 8, again regardless of the actual length of the recording.

Answer (score 0):

Based on that code sample you've pasted in, you could be doing a couple of things incorrectly. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe you are trying to request a `Recording` resource back from the Twilio API after you've submitted one with the Twilio js and their `TwiML`?

If so, twilio actually has a nice little [demo](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/twilio-client-record) of exactly your use case.

You shouldn't see anything in the `$_REQUEST['RecordingDuration']`, I'm not sure why you are even getting a value of 8 returned. Basically what you want to do is find the users recordings by using the Twilio REST API.

here is an example snippet:

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "ACda6f132a3c49700934481addd5ce1659"; 
$token = "{{ auth_token }}"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

// Loop over the list of recordings and echo a property for each one
foreach ($client->account->recordings as $recording) {
    echo $recording->duration;
}
```

The response from the API call will return a Recording resource.

Here is some more examples from their [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording)

Comment: You are correct with your first statement, I am trying to get information about the recording I just submitted with the Twilio js and their TwiML.  However, I've also tried something similar to the example snippet you provided and it continues to return the same value.  I'll edit my original question to include the attempt as well to clarify.

Comment: hmm, assuming you're correctly using the twilio php client, and successfully receiving `Recording` resources as the response object. The only other thing I can think of is, 1) are you sure you have not set a max recording duration of 8 seconds? and 2) Are the test recordings silent? If so, Twilio trims silence from your audio files see there [hints](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#hints) section

Comment: I've got the max recording set to 1000 seconds at the moment but if I remember correctly, it can go for much longer than that.  And I have been doing very short, 1-2 second recordings for the most part but occasionally will do a longer one.  I do have about 5 seconds of silence that I have to wait through right now in order for the recording to be considered over so maybe that's where it's coming from?

Comment: I just find it strange that the duration of the recording with the silence still attached at the end would be the one returned instead of the duration of the recording after the silence been trimmed as it displays for your recordings on the Twilio site and in the actual recording files.